# javascript how to split between and store in an array

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to split between a string that contain a number image src and store them in an array. for now i can only get 1 image src, how can I loop through and store all src images into an array?

```
var s = contentHtml;
//splits the first src
var arrStr = s.split('<img src="').pop().split('"').shift();

var numofimg = (s.split('<img src="').length - 1);

var myarray = [numofimg];

if (numofimg != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numofimg; i++) {


    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a live document where `contentHtml` was originally read from, or is it just a string? In other words, are those image elements on the page?

Comment: its just a string

Comment: Is the `contentHTML` string just a series of `<img>` tags? i.e. `'<img src="foo.jpg"><img src="bar.jpg"><img src="banana.jpg">'`?

Comment: In that case you could make a temporary element or a document fragment, add the string as html, and make a DOM query to get the `src`s of the images.

Comment: I'd still suggest putting the string's content in a live page via `element.innerHTML = contentHtml` and go from there through the DOM

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You are ignoring any closing tag or the html  in the string is invalid. Hard to help without a proper example

Comment: yeah Mathew im just trying to get the content within a series of img tags

Comment: You would never want to use split on a html element. Especially not to get it's src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this with just strings (i.e. all of the img tags are consistently formatted, no extra attributes, etc.) you can use a regular expression to handle it.

```js
var contentHtml = "<html>Some junk<img src=\"abc.jpg\" />Some junk<img src=\"def.jpg\" /><p>Some junk<img src=\"9000.gif\" /></p></html>";

var results = [];
var rgx = /<img src="([^"]+)"/g;
var match;

while (match = rgx.exec(contentHtml)) {
    results.push(match[1]);  // match[1] contains the captured group
}

console.log(results);
```

If it's a more complex document or not consistent, there are probably better ways to do it.

Comment: this only seem to output numbers?

Comment: Gotcha.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var strImages = '<img src="afoo.jpg"><img src="bar.jpg"><img src="banana.jpg">';
var rePattern = /src="(.+?)"/g;
var arSources = [];

reMatch = rePattern.exec(strImages);

while (reMatch !== null) {
  arSources.push(reMatch[0]);
  reMatch = rePattern.exec(strImages);
};

console.log(arSources);
```